# Jquery append html file many times with passing parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem when I try to seperate html code from js file.
I want to create html file from tr tag but I don't know how to passing value to html file from js file. And then, js file will call to append html many times.
Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you in advance

```
function myusr_lst_get(myData, txtSts, rslt){
    try {
        var myData = null;
        var ret = JSON.parse(rslt.responseText);
        if( ret.ret != null && ret.ret == true) {
            var myData = null;
            if( ret.ret_msg != null ) {
                myData = ret.ret_msg;
            }
            if( myData != null && myData.length > 0 ) {
                for(var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
                    $('#lst_tblbody').append('<tr><td>'+ myData[i].user_name +'</td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if(confirm(\'Do you want to delete? \')){user_delete(\''+ myData[i].user_name +'\');} else { return false;};"><img width="90" height="35" alt="CLICK" src="./img/com/btn_del.png"></a></td></tr>');
                }
            }
        } else {
        alert("Error\n(" + ret.err_msg + ")");
        }
    } catch( e ){
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working as expected ?

Comment: Actually, I cannot handle the variable in html file.

Comment: please add a snippet or a fiddle!

Comment: you can see the string in append statement. And I want to replace this string with new html file.

Answer (score 0):

`Append` add each element when you pass on parameter, but each `''` is one parameter.

Please try with `after` event. `After` accept multiple data

```
function myusr_lst_get(myData, txtSts, rslt){
    try {
        var myData = null;
        var ret = JSON.parse(rslt.responseText);
        if( ret.ret != null && ret.ret == true) {
            var myData = null;
            if( ret.ret_msg != null ) {
                myData = ret.ret_msg;
            }
            if( myData != null && myData.length > 0 ) {
                for(var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
                    $('#lst_tblbody').after('<tr><td>'+ myData[i].user_name +'</td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if(confirm(\'Do you want to delete? \')){user_delete(\''+ myData[i].user_name +'\');} else { return false;};"><img width="90" height="35" alt="CLICK" src="./img/com/btn_del.png"></a></td></tr>');
                }
            }
        } else {
        alert("Error\n(" + ret.err_msg + ")");
        }
    } catch( e ){
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of append tr tag in for loop first create html string and then append to the element, this will also improve performance.

```
var str = '';  
for(var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
str +='<tr><td>'+ myData[i].user_name +'</td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if(confirm(\'Do you want to delete? \')){user_delete(\''+ myData[i].user_name +'\');} else { return false;};"><img width="90" height="35" alt="CLICK" src="./img/com/btn_del.png"></a></td></tr>';
            }
$('#lst_tblbody').append(str);
```

Comment: Can you explain `also`? What else is beneficial except `performance` ?

Comment: No error, but I want to try another way (create html) and append this file instead of using the string.